# How can I solve equations by matching prefactors?

Tags: equation-solving

I have complicated expressions involving traces, for example `tr[a]`, `tr[a^2]`, `tr[a]^2`, `tr[a]tr[a^2]`, and so on. I would like to solve equations where the prefactors of the traces are automatically matched. Consider the following simple example:

$$\frac{2}{N} (\text{tr}\, a)^2 = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{N}} \text{tr}\, a - \alpha_3 \frac{(N^2-2\, \text{tr}\, (a^2))}{\sqrt{2}N} - \alpha_4 \frac{(N-2\, (\text{tr}\, a)^2)}{\sqrt{2}N}\,, \tag{1}$$

for which the solution is:

$$\alpha_1 = 1\,, \quad \alpha_2 = 0\,, \quad \alpha_3 = 0\,, \quad \alpha_4 = \sqrt{2}\,. \tag{2}$$

However the naive application of `Solve` does not produce this solution:

```
Solve[(2 tr[a]^2)/N == \[Alpha][1] + (Sqrt[2] tr[a] \[Alpha][2])/Sqrt[N] - ((N^2 - 2 tr[a^2]) \[Alpha][3])/(Sqrt[2] N) - ((N - 2 tr[a]^2) \[Alpha][4])/(Sqrt[2] N), {\[Alpha][1], \[Alpha][2], \[Alpha][3], \[Alpha][4]}]
(*{{\[Alpha][4] -> (2 Sqrt[2] tr[a]^2)/(-N + 2 tr[a]^2) + (Sqrt[2] N \[Alpha][1])/(N - 2 tr[a]^2) + (2 Sqrt[N] tr[a] \[Alpha][2])/(N - 2 tr[a]^2) - ((N^2 - 2 tr[a^2]) \[Alpha][3])/(N - 2 tr[a]^2)}}*)
```

How can I tell `Solve` to match the traces, or alternately to produce solutions independent of the traces?

Comment: Note that I chose a simple example above that does not contain products such as e.g. `tr[a]tr[a^2]`, but the solution should also be able to understand that prefactors of `tr[a^2]` and prefactors of `tr[a]tr[a^2]` are independent.

Comment: Try `Coefficient[...,{tr[a], tr[a^2], tr[a]^2}]` to get the equations

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don' t think that works for the case I mentioned in my comment. Try `Coefficient[2 tr[a] tr[a^2], {tr[a], tr[a^2], tr[a] tr[a^2]}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic advice: `N` is a protected system symbol with a built-in meaning; don't use it. In fact, avoid all capital letters and starting your symbol names with a capital.

The functionality you are looking for is given by `SolveAlways`. You have to have an equation that can be put in the form of a polynomial in the "variables"; here they are `{tr[a], tr[a^2], $n}`, where `$n` is my substitute for `Sqrt[N]`.

```
SolveAlways[(2 tr[a]^2)/
    N == α[1] + (Sqrt[2] tr[a] α[2])/
     Sqrt[N] - ((N^2 - 2 tr[a^2]) α[3])/(Sqrt[
        2] N) - ((N - 2 tr[a]^2) α[4])/(Sqrt[2] N) /. N -> $n^2,
 {tr[a], tr[a^2], $n}]

(*  {{α[1] -> 1, α[2] -> 0, α[3] -> 0, α[4] -> Sqrt[2]}}  *)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!